# Why is there some difference in receive time and sound of a sent SMS in a mobile device equipped with 2 Sim-card's?

Tags: android, sms

Apparently identifying the phone numbers of a mobile device does not have a comprehensive solution in `Android` and it may differ from one device to another
But if the phone number is known then validating if the mobile device is equipped with a `Sim-card` with that phone number is possible:
Sending `SMS` to that phone number by the application and then reading `SMS` inbox to make sure that the message is received there

I have a mobile device which is equipped with 2 `Sim-card`'s (2 phone numbers)
Let's name the phone numbers as following:

```
Phone-number-A
Phone-number-B
```

When I send a test `SMS` from `Phone-number-A` to `Phone-number-B`:
It takes some seconds to receive the `SMS` in the SMS inbox
There is sound of `SMS` ringtone when receiving the message

When I send a test `SMS` from `Phone-number-A` to `Phone-number-A`:
It is instantly in the `SMS` inbox
There is ***no*** sound of `SMS` ringtone when receiving the message

When I send a test `SMS` from `Phone-number-B` to `Phone-number-A`:
It takes some seconds to receive the `SMS` in the SMS inbox
There is sound of `SMS` ringtone when receiving the message

When I send a test `SMS` from `Phone-number-B` to `Phone-number-B`:
It is instantly in the `SMS` inbox
There is ***no*** sound of `SMS` ringtone when receiving the message

Why is there some difference in receive time and sound ?

Comment: When there is a chat screen opened for specified number and you send to it, there is no sound, as it appears in the same screen.

Comment: ok, what about the time ?

Comment: Most probably how phone handle messages. From the operator side, all messages are the same way handled.